# Name of this distribution?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification

Does anyone know the name of this distribution?

What I'm showing below is a likelihood function, given some data points, x1,...,xn, where x can have values like 0, 1, 2,...

$f(x|\theta)=\theta(1-\theta)^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$

The background is that this distribution turns up in an exercise involving a Beta-Binomial conjugate analysis. That is, the parameter theta has some Beta(a,b) prior. One can then work out the posterior up to proportionality:

$\theta^1 (1-\theta)^{\sum x_i} \times \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}= \theta^{a+1-1} (1-\theta)^{b+\sum x_i-1}$

So the posterior would be Beta(a+1,b+ $\sum$ x_i).

This was a problem that I saw somewhere. I just want to know whether there is some name for the likelihood function shown above, i.e., which probability mass function it corresponds to.

Comment: This looks like a geometric distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Agree with @periwinkle, but what exactly is $x$ in here? What kind of data is is?

Comment: Close, but a geometric distribution doesn’t have that summation. We never see $n$ defined in the question.

Comment: Sorry, n is the number of data points. So: it could be data like x_1, x_2, ..., x_n.

Comment: This needs clarification, because if $n$ really is a number of "data points,* then $f$ is not a distribution: it's a likelihood.  And it doesn't look like a valid likelihood.  Could you please provide some background or context for understanding your question?

Comment: Did you forget to write the exponent of $\theta$?

Comment: no, i really meant it as i wrote it! :)